# Create custom button in form ui-component Magento 2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I want to add a custom button like image.

I tried this code in ui-component but it not show

Code for Button

```
<button name="save" class="Anshu\Custom\Block\Adminhtml\Custom\Edit\SaveButton"/>
```

My block

```
<?php

namespace Anshu\Custom\Block\Adminhtml\Custom\Edit;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

/**
 * Class SaveButton
 */
class CreateOrder extends GenericButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Create Order'),
            'class' => 'save primary',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => ['button' => ['event' => 'save']],
                'form-role' => 'save',
            ],
            'sort_order' => 20,
        ];
    }
}
```

My form xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">suppliers_form.suppliers_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">suppliers_form.suppliers_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Lieferanten Informationen</item>
        <item name="layout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">tabs</item>
            <item name="navContainerName" xsi:type="string">left</item>
        </item>

        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">abc\Suppliers\Block\Adminhtml\Suppliers\Button\Back</item>
            <item name="save_and_continue" xsi:type="string">abc\Suppliers\Block\Adminhtml\Suppliers\Button\SaveAndContinueButton</item>
            <item name="save" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">save</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Save</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/save</item>
            </item>

        </item>
    </argument>

    <dataSource name="suppliers_form_data_source">
        <!--  Core cua UI Component -->
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <!-- -->
        <settings>
            <submitUrl path="suppliers/index/save"/>
        </settings>

        <dataProvider class="abc\Suppliers\Ui\Component\Suppliers\Form\DataProvider" name="suppliers_form_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>

    <dataSource name="suppliers_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">abc\Suppliers\Model\Suppliers\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">suppliers_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="suppliers/index/save" />
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>

    <fieldset name="general">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">General Information</label>
        </settings>

        <field name="suppliers_id">
            <settings>
                <imports>
                    <link name="disabled">${ $.provider }:data.disabled</link>
                </imports>
            </settings>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Lieferanten-ID</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">general</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Lieferanten Name</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">general</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="land">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">abc\Suppliers\Model\DataSource\Options</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Lieferanten Land</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">general</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="customer_number_supplier">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Kundennummer beim Lieferanten</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">general</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="contact_person_supplier">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Kontaktperson beim Lieferanten</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">general</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="supplier_email_address">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Lieferanten E-Mail Adresse</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">general</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="suppliers_phone_number">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Lieferanten Telefonnummer</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">general</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="suppliers_fax_number">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Lieferanten Faxnummer</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">general</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="comment_supplier">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Kommentar zum Lieferanten</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">general</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="supplier_email_text">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Liefranten E-Mail Text</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">general</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset name="artikel_nachbestellen">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Artikel nachbestellen</label>
        </settings>

        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"></item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">general</item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <container name="artikel_nachbestellen" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>

            <htmlContent name="html_content">
                <block class="abc\Suppliers\Block\Adminhtml\Product" template="abc_Suppliers::products.phtml" name="abc.suppliers.products">
                <block class="abc\Suppliers\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Grid" name="abc.suppliers.products.grid" />
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Serializer" name="productgrid_grid_serializer">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="input_names" xsi:type="string">qty
                            </argument>
                            <argument name="grid_block" xsi:type="string">abc.suppliers.products.grid</argument>
                            <argument name="callback" xsi:type="string">getSelectedProducts</argument>
                            <argument name="input_element_name" xsi:type="string">products</argument>
                            <argument name="reload_param_name" xsi:type="string">products</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </htmlContent>
        </container>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Rohan Hapani, please check update question

Comment: Try insertListing component to UI Form

Comment: try this link https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-button.html

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this**

```
<form>
    ...
    <fieldset>
        ...
        <button name="custom_button">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="buttonClasses" xsi:type="string">custom-button-class</item>
                    <item name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="targetName" xsi:type="string">TARGET_NAME</item>
                            <item name="actionName" xsi:type="string">ACTION_NAME</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <displayAsLink>false</displayAsLink>
                <title translate="true">Custom Button</title>
            </settings>
        </button>
        <button name="custom_button_as_link">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="buttonClasses" xsi:type="string">custom-button-as-link-class</item>
                    <item name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="targetName" xsi:type="string">TARGET_NAME</item>
                            <item name="actionName" xsi:type="string">ACTION_NAME</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <displayAsLink>true</displayAsLink>
                <title translate="true">Custom Button As Link</title>
            </settings>
        </button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```